# quiver3 with cylinders instead of arrows in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I have a vector field that is defined in a 2D plane. This means that the Z component of the position is constant, but vectors are 3D. I have plotted this using quiver3 as below:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-pi/2:pi/8:pi/2,-pi/2:pi/8:pi/2);
Z=ones(size(X));
U=rand(size(X));
V=rand(size(X));
W=rand(size(X));
H=quiver3(X,Y,Z,U,V,W,'r');
H.ShowArrowHead = 'off';
```

The above code does the job, but it does not look good. Is it possible to represent the vector field like the below picture with 3D rods?

[image]

Comment: Is Matlab able to do such a graph at all?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if MATLAB _itself_ can create such plots, because it's possible to call many other popular plotting libraries from MATLAB (including python, JS, etc.). Do you have know which tool/software _can_ create such charts?